# Encryption Algorithms to Store UII & PII using Java Technologies

Tags: java, pci-dss, pii

What type of algorithms (e.g. AES) are useful for encrypting / storing a user's personally identifiable information (PII) and uniquely identifiable information (UII) using Java technologies?

e.g. What are the standard ways to encrypt / store Social Security Numbers (SSNs) and birthdays?

It simply just encrypting this data using a specific algorithm and then storing it inside a database?

Are there any 3rd party open source libraries that Java developers can use?

Comment: "*To legally store Social Security Numbers (SSNs) and birthdays are there any compliance rules that need to be followed?*" - This probably depends on national law. All-in-all, this seems more like a question for a lawyer (e.g. what has to be done) than a question for SO. Furthermore, a throughout answer would probably too long for SO. Thus, the question seems off-topic.

Comment: @Turing85 thanks for response. Even though I did ask that question, there are other questions (like the type of encryption algorithm) which are technical and are relevant for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Then you should ask the specific question separately, in dedicated questions. But at least wrt. encryption algorithm I would recommend using a pre-existing, well tested implementation.

Comment: @Turing85 - Thanks, I changed the content and the title based on your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a lawyer, but I think it depends.

I don't think there are special libraries that you can add to your project and be GDPR compliant.

Much of GDPR compliance is on the organizational side: get the [user's consent](https://gdpr-info.eu/art-7-gdpr/) to process data for the given purpose, limit your data collection to what you absolutely need (e.g., don't ask for anything but the email address when someone signs up for your newsletter), allow people to [see what data you have stored](https://gdpr-info.eu/art-15-gdpr/) on them, allow people to have their data [deleted](https://gdpr-info.eu/art-17-gdpr/) or [corrected](https://gdpr-info.eu/art-16-gdpr/). Have [contracts with people and companies](https://gdpr-info.eu/art-28-gdpr/) that process data for you. Document your data collection and storage. Have a [data protection officer](https://gdpr-info.eu/art-37-gdpr/) and a [plan on how to work with people's data](https://gdpr-info.eu/art-35-gdpr/).

If you want to [pseudonymize](https://gdpr-info.eu/art-32-gdpr/) user data, AES is a bad choice as it's reversible. A hash function would be better. That way you could e.g., hash all the IP addresses in your server logs and would still be able to see that x% of your traffic came from just one IP address. If you want to anonymize user data, just remove it, e.g., completely remove the IP address form your server logs.

Encrypting data before storing it in a database is probably a moot point too, since you still have the key to decrypt (maybe even somewhere on the same system), it doesn't really protect much.

GDPR does calls for [protecting the users' data](https://gdpr-info.eu/art-24-gdpr/), and that touches on both technical (i.e., use a recent TLS version for network connections, encrypt the hard drives and keep the key in a bank vault) to physical security (have the servers in a safe place with a mean dog and a meaner security guy at the door).